# Can't get video output on avi to mp4 conversion using ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mp4, avi

I am so frustrated with this problem. Any time I convert `avi` files to `mp4` files, I can get the audio, but **NO** video. Here are the various switches I've tried. I don't know how to resolve the situation. I've never had this problem with `mpg`, `mov` or any other format, but **`AVI`** is frustrating.

Doing this in php but I've also done it from the command line.

(**NOTE:** I've also tried it with NO extra parameters letting ffmpeg do the full conversion).

(**NOTE:** It does play the original avi file in any desired Windows or Linux player as is so I know there are is no damage to the original file, but I want to convert to mp4 for the web).

(**Final Note*:** when using `aac` it warns of too many bits ...clamping to max if that helps)

**Here's the code:**

```
$InputFile - some avi file. I have a ton of them and they all do the same thing.

$OutputFile - same name but with an mp4 extension

$Parameters are various switches I've used. 

shell_exec ("ffmpeg -i  " . $InputFile . ' ' . $Parameters . ' ' . $OutputFile);

$Parameters =  " -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p ";

$Parameters = " -acodec copy -vcodec copy ";

$Parameters = " -c:v libx264 -c:a libfaac -movflags +faststart ";

$Parameters = " -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -movflags +faststart ";

$Parameters = " -c:v libx264 -c:a -acodec aac libfdk_aac -movflags +faststart ";

$Parameters = " -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -f mp4 ";

$Parameters =  " -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -preset slow -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -ac 2 ";
```

I really don't get why I only get an audio output. I can see it in VLC player, but, of course that's not my goal. I want it to `mp4` to see it on a webpage.

I welcome any help!

Comment: Need to see full log for the first two parameters.

Comment: Can I ask a foolish question. How to attach it? It's a very long log and it makes a mess when pasting it to the screen. Should I attach it as a file?

Comment: Upload to Pastebin and share links.

Comment: link #1 https://pastebin.com/4fd74g1q

Comment: link #2 https://pastebin.com/4ryLtfEC

Comment: Try `$Parameters =  " -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_track_timescale 600 ";`

Comment: That did it. Can you explain to me what you did because you saved me a LOT of headaches. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU